# Eclipse Tomcat issue , button is disable

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[image]

see in an image the black rectangle pointed out my problem . Where the start button is not green (actually, it is disabled). How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Java application is a Java SE application (Java Standard Edition), it doesn't need any server for running.

When you create Java EE application (Java Enterprise Edition - web application, server is must have), server will be able active.